# What happens when you mlock(2) memory that is already swapped?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, security, swap

Simple question, but I couldn't find an answer.

If there's a page in memory that has already been swapped out to disk by the kernel, and then its owner process calls mlock(2) or VirtualLock on that page in memory, what happens?

Is it swapped back to physical memory immediately? Is it wiped from disk? If one delays the writing of sensitive information into a page until after mlock(2) is called, would that guarantee that it isn't written to disk?

As a minor follow-up question, what would you do to mitigate against such an eventuality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a current upstream version of the Linux kernel, it will force the pages to be faulted back in, but appears to leave copies in swap.

I believe most BSD systems and other UNIX systems behave similarly, not sure about Windows though.

Delaying writing anything until after mlock() is called will prevent the data from being swapped out, but can not guarantee the data won't be written to disk unless ACPI S4 and OS mediated hibernation are not possible and you're not in a VM (if you're in a VM, you could be under a type 1 hypervisor, and therefore subject to the host system's virtual memory constraints, which you can't control).

As a result, proper mitigation involves:

- Handling at the application level to prevent sensitive data from residing in RAM longer than it needs to, even if the region is locked.
- Handling at the system level to disable ACPI S4 (usually only needed on OEM systems), prevent OS mediated hibernation, and ensure trust in the host system if running in a VM.

Comment: Do you have any pointers about somewhere I could find out about Window's policy?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  I checked on Linux using a bare bones test program and some creative scripting with control groups to force data in the program to be swapped out.  The statement about *BSD is mostly based on the fact that Linux tends to behave very similarly to BSD systems when dealing with stuff like this, so you might want to double check that too.